# How identify whether HDR video is HDR10(+) or Dolby Vision?

Tags: ffprobe, hdr

There has been [questions](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22059/how-to-identify-hdr-video) like this in the past, but as the topic states, can one diffrentiate a HDR video whether it is HDR10-compatible or Dolby Vision compatible, or both, with tools such as ffprobe and or mediainfo.